# Why is the resistance not zero even though the length of wire is zero?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I need help about a resistivity lab that I am doing for senior project.

I successfully plotted the (resistance) vs (length of nichrome wire) graph and added the best-fit line however the y-intercept is nonzero. How should I understand this? As a systematic error or some kind of indication of some quantity?

In theory, length is directly proportional to resistance under constant temperature so I am messed up why the graph does not go through the origin.

Comment: There is also [contact resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_resistance) between interfaces.

Comment: @Qmechanic turn this into a full answer

Comment: Draw a circuit diagram. Every circuits question should have a diagram.

Comment: This question could be improved in a few ways: 1) Show the plot of resistance versus length that you measured. 2) Draw a circuit diagram.  Circuit questions are enormously easier to answer if you draw a diagram.

Comment: without knowing the uncertainties on your data it is impossible to say.  does a straight line through the origins fit within the error bars of your data?

Comment: A physics reason could be that the drop close to zero is following a different curve , which falls rapidly to zero when close to zero and for intervals  much denser than the ones you have.

Comment: What happens if you simply touch the two leads of the ohmeter? What is the resistance reading?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, empirical data is subject to errors in the test setup and measuring equipment. But still you should try to account for the known sources of error. This includes errors in the measuring device, like calibration errors or your ohmmeter might not compensate for the resistance of the test leads, etc. For starters, short the test leads/contacts without the nichrome wire present. That will tell you how much resistance you need to subtract from all measurements.

Comment: good point.  calibration is very important.